# How to calculate a Cartesian product of a list with itself

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

For example,

```
list = [0, 1, 2]
```

I want a list of all possible 2-combinations:

```
combinations = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]
```

It seems to me that all the tools in itertools in Python only make one of (1,0) and (0,1), not both, I need both. Any suggestions, other than entering them by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a Cartesian product of that list with itself, not a permutation nor a combination. Therefore you should use `itertools.product` with `repeat=2`:

```
from itertools import product

li = [0, 1, 2]
print(list(product(li, repeat=2)))
>> [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by importing itertools:

```
import itertools

list1 = [0, 1, 2]
print(list(itertools.product(list1,repeat=2)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Resource:
You can learn more about it -
[here](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/11/how-do-use-itertools-in-python-to-build-permutation-or-combination/)